# How to avoid the text inside the bootstrap button overflow?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap button [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/x69chen/2F7EG/7/)

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid" id="index-nav">
    <div class="span2 offset3">
      <a class="btn btn-large" href="#">Administration</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.btn-large {
    width: 81%;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Setting the width is to make sure that the button could be limited in the specific span area.

but however, when I drag back to re-size the result window inside JSFiddle, the text seems overflow from the button like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, try adding `word-wrap:break-word;` to your button's CSS style?